# hibernate select foreign-key property is null

Tags: hibernate

I have the following two beans:

**model1:**

```
Man { 
id, 
name 
}
```

**model2:**

```
Girl { 
id, 
name, 
(Man)man 
}
```

I want to find girls that have no man using hql.

What I tried:

```
from Girl n where n.man.id is null
```

but the result list is empty!
I find the reason is because when we query the foreign key property, hibernate will auto inner join the two tables, so can't query result with the null foreign key property list.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (works on Hibernate 5 too)

```
select g from Girl g where not exists elements(g.man)
```

Comment: not working, "nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException", I have no idea.

Comment: you are doing sth wrong. I have already tested the same query with my entities and it is working without problems and returning correct results. post you full code and the exact line of the exception.

Comment: String hql="from Account n where not exists elements(n.role)"; // java.lang.NullPointerException
  hql= "from Account n"; // this can working
  baseService.queryHql(hql, new Object[]{});

Comment: how can your first hql return empty set and then you run this and it throws null pointer exception? cant understand it.

Comment: the wrong exception is using the elements function, not using "is null", and I find the real reason is using "union all" in the hql is not working, and using "is null" can query list. So my question is how use "union all" in the hql.

Comment: I have three tables that they are Application, Role, Account. Then I use the hql "from Account n where n.role.application.id=?", but Hibernate genertate the sql is "select * from account n, role m where n.role_id=m.id and m.application_id=?". So the accounts that have no role can't query out. I know if the hql use "left join" to connect account table and role table can reach my purpose. I wish you can help me, thanks!